# Django OneToMany design?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, one-to-many

I stuck on a simple design decision with some Django Models.
As from my understanding either a Foreignkey nor a ManyToMany fits in here.

Let's take the pizza/topping example from the Django docs to work with:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    # ...
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

This is clearly a ManyToMany relationship.

Now let's take another example. I have 10 bikes to lend out, and also I have some equipment (i.e. helm, gloves).

Then the Model should be:

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    # ...

class Equipment(models.Model):
    # ...

class LendBike(models.Model):
    # ...
    bike = models.ForeignKeyField(Bike)
    equipment_1 = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
    equipment_2 = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
    ...
```

But how can I manage this **if I don't know how many equipment** someone got?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood but the first code example seems to work in both cases. If you can't foresee how many toppings will exist, you'd better use a solution that can manage all the cases.

Comment: No in the second example I only have ONE TOPPING EACH. So i.e. 1 slice salami, 1 onion, 1 mushroom ;)
I'll edit the qeustion with a better example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A design using events can help you to track actions of your users.
In the code bellow, you have 3 classes dedicated to your stuff here (Bike, Glove, Helmet), and an Event class which will be instantiated every time a user borrow stuff or render stuff.

With all this data in your database, you are able to know the state of your stuff (borrowed or available) in real time plus have an history of everything.

You can add fields like "lender" to your stuff classes, but it's not DRY and can create inconsistency. On the other hand, it can help you to NOT create impossible events (like borrowing already borrowed stuff).

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    lender = models.ForeignKeyField(User)
    # lender == None means your Bike is available!

class Glove(models.Model)
    lender = models.ForeignKeyField(User)

class Helmet(models.Model)
    lender = models.ForeignKeyField(User)

class BorrowOrRenderEvent(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Stuff borrowed or rendered (we assume we can't borrow AND render stuff in the same event)
    bike = models.ForeignKeyField(Bike)
    gloves = models.ManyToManyField(GloveEquipment)
    helmets = models.ManyToManyField(HelmetEquipment)

    # Who is performing this action?
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    # We need to know if the event is about borrowing or rendering stuff
    is_rendering = models.BooleanField()
```

**How to know how many equipment someone currently got?**

In a class that extends the User class, add a method like this:

```
def count_borrowed_equipment_per_user(self):
    nb_bikes = Bike.objects.filter(lender=self.user).count()
    nb_helmets = Helmet.objects.filter(lender=self.user).count()
    nb_gloves = Glove.objects.filter(lender=self.user).count()
    return nb_bikes, nb_helmets, nb_gloves
```

**Note**

I'd like to tell that in my opinion, in general and in that case, database only cannot ensure functional consistency. It's easy to insert crap in DB even with good designing, if your business logic is bad :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this still leaves the Equipment alone. I have no chance to see if and where an Equipment object is in use (see also answer and comments from bogdan)

Comment: Oh I didn't understand that you needed to know in real time who got what. With an 'Event' system (see my updated code) this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    # ...

class Equipment(models.Model):
    # ...

class LendBike(models.Model):
    # ...
    bike = models.ForeignKeyField(Bike)
    equipments = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment)
```

A M2M relation between `LendBike` and `Equipment` this way you can assign as many equipment as you like.

Comment: Yes, that's clear so far. But this wayx I would be able to give away one piece of Equipment more than one time.

Comment: In this case you probably want to add a `lended` BooleanField on the equipment and don't assign until it is returned.

Comment: This might be a way. I'm thinking about adding the ID of the LendBike object back into Equipment (with a ForeignKey). This would also give me the possibility to see **where** an Equipment object is in use.
But all this does not _feel_ right as this is not completly covered by the database.